# Type of linking that Python - PySide and Qt libraries do between each other?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I would like to understand Static and Dynamic linking of libraries in case of Python and C/C++ combinations.

What type of linking do Python Interpreter, PySide Qt Bindings and Qt itself have between each other?

How does it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, the conversion from C++ to python is done by [SIP](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/). Look at the example code, especially [this one](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/using.html#a-simple-c-example).

For each Qt class, there is a corresponding SIP specification file.